# Howto build pepper in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lua, statistics

I'm currently struggling to get pepper (https://jgehring.github.io/pepper/)
configured and build under Ubuntu 14.04.

I fail with the configuration for Lua 5.2. 
How is the right configure-command-line?

```
 $./configure  --prefix=/tmp/pepper
 configure:7587: found /usr/bin/lua
 configure:7599: result: /usr/bin/lua
 configure:7637: checking Lua version is in range 501 <= v < 
 configure:7662: result: no
 configure:7664: error: in `/tmp/pepper-0.3.3':
 configure:7666: error: Lua version not in desired range.
```

Lua is installed in version 5.2

```
 $ /usr/bin/lua -v
 Lua 5.2.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2011 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

 $ dpkg -L liblua5.2-dev
 /usr/include/lua5.2/lua.h
 /usr/include/lua5.2/luaconf.h
 /usr/include/lua5.2/lauxlib.h
 /usr/include/lua5.2/lualib.h
 /usr/include/lua5.2/lua.hpp
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.a
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so
```

Thank you in advance, Axel.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it turned out that lua5.1 is required.

```
sudo apt-get install liblua5.1 liblua5.1-dev lua5.1
sh ./autogen.sh
./configure --with-lua-suffix=5.1 
make
make install
```

An additional step that should be mentioned is upgrading and switching to an C-compiler that supports -std=g++11 as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/522387/std-c11-not-recognized-on-gcc-4-8-1

Just in case the above link disappears, here are the commands to switch the g++/gcc compiler:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
sudo rm /usr/bin/cpp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/g++
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cpp-4.9 /usr/bin/cpp
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: Pretty nice tool indeed that gives some insight in what is going on in the project/repo.